# Find two points in a given set of points in 2D plane with least distance in less than O(n^2) time

Tags: performance, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I was asked this question in Yahoo for machine learning profile. Given a set of points (x,y) coordinates I was asked to find points with lowest distance in O(n) or O(log n )time.
Obviously I was able to come up with O(n^2) time but was no way near getting the better algorithm. Even though the problem statement was screaming for Divide and Conquer I just could not come up with the reasoning for the merge step. I also googled for this question on the internet and found that It is actually very popular but I still could not get hold of the reasoning of the merge step.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Input: (x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4),(x5,y5)

Comment: This should be posted in the mathsection ;) O(n) means linear with the amount of points. Is that possible? You just compared every pair of points right ?

Comment: yes in O(n^2 ) algorithm I did that n*(n-1)/2 complexity

Comment: maybe this could help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

Answer (score 6):

The problem can be solved in O(n log n) time using the recursive divide and conquer approach, e.g., as follows:

1.Sort points according to their x-coordinates.

2.Split the set of points into two equal-sized subsets by a vertical line x=xmid.

3.Solve the problem recursively in the left and right subsets. This yields the left-side and right-side minimum distances dLmin and dRmin, respectively.

4.Find the minimal distance dLRmin among the pair of points in which one point lies on the left of the dividing vertical and the second point lies to the right.

5.The final answer is the minimum among dLmin, dRmin, and dLRmin.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points

Comment: Yep, surprisingly the "middle' part of the recursive algo is O(1) because you only need to check at most three points on each side of the middle two points.